# Pug increase the number 'inside' array name

Tags: javascript, pug

I'm using PUG and I have arrays as below

```
-let filter0 = ['Category', 'Brand', 'Price', 'Color']
-let filter1 = ['Category 1', 'Category 2', 'Category 3']
-let filter2 = ['Brand 1', 'Brand 2']
-let filter3 = ['Price 1', 'Price 2']
-let filter4 = ['Color 1', 'Color 2']
```

`filter0` defines my titles.

The rest (`filter#`) defines sub categories of each title.

I want to increase the name of array in every loop same as class names.

```
each val, index in filter0
  input(class='toggle' id='toggle'+index type='checkbox')
  label.title(for='toggle'+index)
    = val
  .content
    each val, index in filter1 // This should be filter+index so the result can be filter1,filter2 etc.
      ul
        li
          input(class='checkbox' id='checkbox-'+index type='checkbox' value='value'+index)
          label(for='checkbox-'+index)= val
```

Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: your first loop use `val`,`index`. and second loop use `val`,`index` too. change variable names.

Comment: @AminTaghikhani yes but then how do I increase the number of array name?

Comment: it's better to use an `object`, each array store as `key:value`, then you can create object `key` and access to array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might want to see the solution for some reason :P
Thanks @AminTaghikhani

```
var filter = {
0: ['Category', 'Brand', 'Price', 'Color'],
1: ['Category 1', 'Category 2', 'Category 3'],
2: ['Brand 1', 'Brand 2'],
3: ['Price 1', 'Price 2'],
4: ['Color 1', 'Color 2']
}
```

```
each x, y in filter[0]
  input(class='toggle' id='toggle'+y type='checkbox')
  label.title(for='toggle'+y)
    = x
  .content
    each a, b in filter[1+y]
      ul
        li
          input(class='checkbox' id='checkbox-'+b+y type='checkbox' value='value'+b+y)
          label(for='checkbox-'+b+y)= a
```